# Get feature information from WFS layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

In case of `OpenLayers 2` I am able to get feature information but how to get feature information from vector or WFS layer in `OpenLayers 3`

Below code how to extract information of the vector layer if multiple vectors are there?

```
  var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function(extent) {
      $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          service: 'WFS',
          version: '1.1.0',
          request: 'GetFeature',
          typename: 'dgm:all_block_boundary_point',
          srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
          bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
        }
      }).done(function(response) {
        layerWFS
        .getSource()
        .addFeatures(new ol.format.WFS()
          .readFeatures(response));
         // console.log(response);
      });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
  })
}); 
map.addLayer(layerWFS);
```

Comment: Do you mean GetFeatureInfo request of a WMS, or GetFeature request of a WFS?

Comment: getFeatureInfo request for  WFS

Comment: There is no such operation.

Comment: i have found solution using var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);


map.on('singleclick', function(event){  
    layerWFS.once('precompose',function(event){
      var selectedFeatures = selectSingleClick.getFeatures();
      readFeature(selectedFeatures);
    });
});

Comment: You should convert your comment into an answer for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution to get feature information of vector layer

```
var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);


map.on('singleclick', function(event){  
    layerWFS.once('precompose',function(event){
      var selectedFeatures = selectSingleClick.getFeatures();
      readFeature(selectedFeatures);
    });
});

function readFeature(features){

   var myfeature = features.item(0);

       Msg = "<center><h4><b>"+myfeature.get('block_name')+" Block</b></h4></center>";
               Msg += "<center><table border='1'>";
                Msg += "<tr><td style='padding: 2px;'>" + 'Block Name' + "</td><td style='padding: 2px;'>" + myfeature.get('block_name') + "</td></tr>"; 
                Msg += "<tr><td style='padding: 2px;'>" + 'Latitude' + "</td><td style='padding: 2px;'>" + myfeature.get('latitude') + "</td></tr>"; 
                Msg += "<tr><td style='padding: 2px;'>" + 'Longitude' + "</td><td style='padding: 2px;'>" + myfeature.get('longitude') + "</td></tr>"; 
                Msg += "</table></center>"; 
    document.getElementById('featuredetails').innerHTML = Msg;


                   var opt = {
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: false,
                        width: 300,
                        height:430,
                        hide: "puff",
                        show : "clip",
                         position : "right",
                        title: 'INFORMATION', 

                      };
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#featuredetails").dialog(opt).dialog("open").parents().css({"z-index": "999"});
              $(".ui-widget-overlay").css({"display" : "none"});
            });

}
```

Comment: I would like to use you example but I get an error that myfeature is undefined